# Use sequence number in active log file

Tags: nlog

I have the following log target defined.

```xml
<target xsi:type="File"
        name="file"
        layout="${defLayout}"
        fileName="${logNamePrefix}.txt"
        archiveFileName="${logNamePrefix}.{######}.txt"
        archiveAboveSize="10485760"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        keepFileOpen="true"
        openFileCacheTimeout="30"
        concurrentWrites="false"
        archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"/>
```

This will give me files like `2021-07-09_13.08.30-Log.txt` that are then renamed to `2021-07-09_13.08.30-Log.000000.txt` once the rollover occurs. The active file is always the one without the sequence number.

I was wondering if there was some way to push the sequence number into the active filename so the active file would always be numbered. The logger would write to `2021-07-09_13.08.30-Log.000000.txt` and then `2021-07-09_13.08.30-Log.000001.txt` and so on.

Comment: You have "cleverly" hidden the value of `${logNamePrefix}`. But it looks like you are mixing dynamic and static archive logic: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target#dynamic-vs-static-archive-logic (Unexpected behavior will occur when mixing)

Comment: Maybe consider changing to static-filename and use `archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"`

Comment: The contents of the prefix is not important to the question but it does resolve to something unique per run that looks like the `2021-07-09_13.08.30-Log` that's in the question.